# Do I need a driver for pen and touch screen in Toshiba Portege M750?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, screen

I have Toshiba Portege M750 with touch screen and pen. After installation of Ubuntu 14.10, the touch screen and pen did not work at all. Is there any driver or a program to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can Install **kde-config-touchpad**:

```
sudo apt-get install kde-config-touchpad
```

Depending on the version, you can choice between switch to on the corresponding buttom or mark a verification box for activate the touchpad. In this way, I solved a similar problem in my **Eee PC 1001PXD Asus**.